# Angular/Typescript get string[] from class keys/interface/type? ts-transformer-keys won't work with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typegoose

So I have an external models/interfaces package published via npm, it is built using typegoose + mongoose, so I can have my interfaces in one place and then use the interfaces/models across multiple apps whilst also keeping them in sync.

[Here's and example of a model/class.](https://github.com/michaelbats/tlabs-models/blob/master/src/Models/contact.models.ts)

Now the issue is, I'm making some dynamic tables on the frontend to work with either collection, so I'm trying to find a way to get the keys as strings whilst keeping it all dynamic in one place.

So far I've tried ts-transformer-keys but due to having to implement some stuff around compile-time, it won't work inside angular.

I also can't use the class directly into angular due to the class extending `Typegoose` which depends on `mongoose` which throws an error about some global thing and then crashes the whole app.

Where `User` is my class which extends Typegoose and `IUser` is the type from that class, things like:

```
class test extends User {}
```

still have mongo dependency error

```
class test implements User{}
```

still need to manually add all properties

```
Object.keys(User)
```

mongoose dependency will throw an error

```
Object.keys(IUser)
```

doesn't woork because type doesn't exist at runtime;

Perhaps a decorator on the class that loops over all the keys & adds the constructor name to the class prototype? That doesn't seem likely to be working at runtime.

**For future readers, [read this github issue](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/33), TL;DR: typegoose currently dosnt support clientside classes**

Comment: The link is dead (I'm getting a Github 404), and showing your code would help more than describing it. At the moment, the problem is just too vague.

Comment: @JeremyThille my bad, I forgot to make the repo public, I just have.

Comment: @JeremyThille also just because you don't understand it doesn't mean it's vague, it's quite a common use case with typescript and there's dozens of extended threads about this issue and use case, all of them recommend ts-transformer-keys which I can't use inside angular so those threads don't address this.